# Clojure :: get the single element of a list and throw exception if the list has more than 1 elements

Tags: clojure

I know at a certain point in my code that a list only has one element so I obtain it with

```
(first alist)
```

But I would also like the code to break if the list has more than one elements to alert me of the erroneous condition. What's an idiomatic way to achieve that in Clojure ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `first` with an `only` (or other poetically named) function with a pre-condition where you want to make your assertion:

```
(defn only [x] {:pre [(nil? (next x))]} (first x))

(only [1])
=> 1

(only [1 2])
=> AssertionError Assert failed: (nil? (next x))  user/only (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

Comment: `(only [1 nil])` illustrates a bug in this solution.

Comment: @AlexBaranosky Care to explain? `(next [1 nil])` is `'(nil)` and `(nil? '(nil))` is `false`. So, `(only [1 nil])` throws an assertion error as desired.

Comment: @A.Webb Hmmm... I must've been imagining things at the time?

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. `(only [1 nil])` should be a failed assertion. The vector has more than one element. It just so happens to be `nil` in this case. `[1 nil 3]` would return `1`.

Comment: @DevinWalters See objection by Alex and response directly above in the comments. This is `next` not `fnext`.

Answer (score 5):

This will blow up on a collection with anything other than one element.  Works fine on lazy seqs as well.

```
(defn only
 "Gives the sole element of a sequence"
 [coll]
 (if (seq (rest coll))
   (throw (RuntimeException. "should have precisely one item, but had at least 2"))
   (if (seq coll)
     (first coll)
     (throw (RuntimeException. "should have precisely one item, but had 0")))))
```

Comment: +1 -- This is a great answer because in addition to avoiding the use of `count` it can handle both `(only nil)` and `(only (sorted-map 1 :a 2 :b))`.

Comment: the name of the argument gives the impression that it only takes _collections_ - concrete, finite aggregates. Consider renaming to indicate that (the more abstract) _sequences_ are also supported.

Answer (score 1):

I can't immediately think of a nice concise, idiomatic way to do this.

Option 1 is that there isn't one, because this is a bit of an odd situation. If you know there's supposed to be exactly one element, why is it in a list in the first place?

Option 2 is that there is one, and someone will come along and tell off for not seeing it :)

That said, in your situation I'd probably write something like:

```
(let [[item & rest] alist]
  (if (nil? rest)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Expected a single-element list"))
    item))
```

Possibly more simply, you could also just do `(count alist)` and make sure it had exactly one item. The code above, though, has the nice property that it won't force evaluation beyond the head of the list, but depending on your use case that might not be a concern.

Comment: I don't like the `count` approach because it isn't a resilient solution for long or infinite sequences.

Answer (score 0):

[The Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#extracting-only-values) has this function defined as a core sanity-check, allowing one to "unwrap" scalar values from length-1 vectors/lists and document the intended result.  The definition is simplicity itself:

```
(defn only
  "(only coll)
  Ensures that a sequence is of length=1, and returns the only value present.
  Throws an exception if the length of the sequence is not one.
  Note that, for a length-1 sequence S, (first S), (last S) and (only S) are equivalent."
  [coll]
  (let [coll-seq  (seq coll)
        num-items (count coll-seq)]
    (when-not (= 1 num-items)
      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "only: num-items must=1; num-items=" num-items))))
    (clojure.core/first coll-seq)))
```

You can find a similar function in the [SuchWow library](https://crossclj.info/fun/such.sequences/only.html) and other places.